# I've made a CURL request but its not working

Tags: php, api, curl

Below is my CURL request. Im trying to pull data from a CRM called pipedrive. The URL is pulling the data correctly but for some reason its not displaying on my website.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons/find?term=devonvermaak2%40gmail.com&start=0&search_by_email=1&api_token=e7f91c84dad486160a9744f4972d7f742de3d",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length": "217",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-ratelimit-limit": "20",
    "x-ratelimit-remaining": "19",
    "x-ratelimit-reset": "2"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
//because of true, it's in an array
$response = json_decode($response, true); 
echo 'Name: '. $response['data']['name']. '<br />';
echo 'Email: '. $response['data']['email']. '<br />';
echo 'Phone: '. $response['data']['phone'];
```

Its not showing the data at all. Is there something wrong with my code?

Note: I've edited the api token for security purposes..

Comment: What is the value of `$response` from the API?

Comment: {"success":true,"data":[{"id":91235,"name":"Devon Vermaak","email":"devonvermaak2@gmail.com","phone":"0555877857","org_id":null,"org_name":"","visible_to":"3"}],"additional_data":{"search_method":"search_by_email","pagination":{"start":0,"limit":100,"more_items_in_collection":false}}}

Comment: The `data` element is an array, so you need `$response['data'][0]['name']`

Comment: Ive added that but the data is still not displaying

Comment: Check the decode JSON by `print_r($response);` after the `json_decode()` line.

Comment: Its not displaying anything.

Comment: I guess there are errors in your syntax. put this in first line of your code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try again. @DevonVermaak

Comment: use `var_dump($response);` to check what's in your response.

Comment: It returns NULL

Answer (score 1):

since your `$response` is

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 91235,
      "name": "Devon Vermaak",
      "email": "devonvermaak2@gmail.com",
      "phone": "0555877857",
      "org_id": null,
      "org_name": "",
      "visible_to": "3"
    }
  ],
  "additional_data": {
    "search_method": "search_by_email",
    "pagination": {
      "start": 0,
      "limit": 100,
      "more_items_in_collection": false
    }
  }
}
```

you can see that the `data` is an `array`

hence, you can access the values via its index. Ex

`$response['data'][0]['name']` returns `Devon Vermaak`

```
echo 'Name: '. $response['data'][0]['name']. '<br />';
echo 'Email: '. $response['data'][0]['email']. '<br />';
echo 'Phone: '. $response['data'][0]['phone'];
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I have it on my side, however its not displaying the data. Also when I print_r the $response it doesnt display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER' array values.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons/find?term=devonvermaak2%40gmail.com&start=0&search_by_email=1&api_token=e7f91c84dad486160a9744f4972d7f742de3d",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control"=> "no-cache",
    "content-length"=> "217",
    "content-type"=> "application/json",
    "x-ratelimit-limit"=> "20",
    "x-ratelimit-remaining"=> "19",
    "x-ratelimit-reset"=> "2"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
//because of true, it's in an array
$response = json_decode($response, true); 
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained what the *Wrong 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER' array values* are

Comment: array format "cache-control":"no-cache" to "cache-control"=> "no-cache",

Comment: Quote manual, _“CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER - An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`”_

Comment: So not `'name' => 'value'`, but `'name: value'`